# How to sort date-time stored as varchar data type in AM/ PM ascending order?

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored data in my table. I want to sort my column named `new_meeting_time` as varchar. I have a query `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY new_meeting_time ASC` and gives me the following output:

```
      1. 17-03-2016 01:26 PM
      2. 17-03-2016 01:31 PM
      3. 17-03-2016 01:34 PM
      4. 17-03-2016 01:44 PM
      5. 17-03-2016 10:33 AM
```

But I want to get data in the following order:

```
        1. 17-03-2016 10:33 AM  
        2. 17-03-2016 01:26 PM
        3. 17-03-2016 01:31 PM  
        4. 17-03-2016 01:34 PM
        5. 17-03-2016 01:44 PM
```

How can i do this?

Comment: what is the datatype of `new_meeting_time`?

Comment: sorry for the wrong oreder. I have corrected it. @DylanSu

Comment: please change datatype of  new_meeting_time from varchar to timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(new_meeting_time, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') ASC
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, please click the grey tick on the left side to accept. so that future users can use

Answer (score 5):

Store your data in a proper format, which is **datetime**.

Solutions from the other answers are just awful performance-wise.

A database is a fine mechsnism. And one should use it properly. If you ask how to harness a horse to drive a car, the proper answer is "buy gasoline".

Answer (score 0):

Try this utilizing `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(new_meeting_time,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p');
```

Demo for the effect of this function:

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('17-03-2016 01:26 PM','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('17-03-2016 01:26 PM','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-03-17 13:26:00                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```